# VIM with ALE for c++ headers

Tags: c++, vim

I am new to using ALE for vim and am trying to configure it for c++ projects. It works reasonably well for `.cpp` files however I am having some difficulty with `.h` files. Even though `:set ft?` reports the type as `cpp`, I still get errors as though it were a `c` file. Although the program compiles, ALE gives me errors when I use `uint32_t` or `bool` types. Is there a reason for this?

Here is the header with the errors inserted in comments.

```cpp
    1 enum WritePolicy {WriteThrough, WriteBack};                                                                                                                                    
    2 enum EvictionPolicy {FIFO, LRU};                                                                                                                                               
    3                                                                                                                                                                                
    4 struct Config {                                                                                                                                                                
    5     int sets;                                                                                                                                                                  
    6     int blocks;
    7     int bytes;
E   8     bool write_allocate; // E: unknown type name 'bool'                                                                                                                        
    9     enum WritePolicy write_policy;                                                                                                                                             
   10     enum EvictionPolicy eviction_policy;                                                                                                                                       
   11 };                                                                                                                                                                             
   12                                                                                                                                                                                
E  13 bool is_power_of_two(int); // E: unknown type name 'bool'                                                                                                                      
   14 int parse_greater_than_or_equal(char*, int, const char*);
```

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker/documentation and possibly the underlying tool's as well.

Comment: Both `uint32_t` and `bool` can work in C as well. Without showing your header file and the exact errors you receive, anything anybody can do is guess.

Comment: @Friedrich I added the header

Comment: You should check `:ALEInfo`. It prints a lot. Pay attention to `g:ale_cpp_cc_header_exts` and see which checkers are installed and running and check their options. BTW, ALE worked out of the box for me so I'll run out of ideas soon :)

Comment: @Friedrich `let g:ale_cpp_cc_header_exts = ['h', 'hpp']`

Comment: @Friedrich It seems like the issue is that I don't have a compilation database for `clang-tidy`. Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: If you want to use clang, you need to use clang :) Create a compilation db (you'll find plenty of resources on this site and others) or switch `clang-tidy` off. I'm not aware of any workarounds.

Comment: @Friedrich Thank you, that makes sense. Are there similar tool that work with GCC toolchains?

Answer (score 1):

As we've found out in the comments, ALE itself runs fine. ALE has the ability to run several static code analyzers per language. Generally, the more you run, the more issues you may find. ALE also comes with extensive documentation, available via Vim's built in help. Start with `:help ale` or - for C++ compilation - `:help ale-cpp-options`. Also refer to the project's GitHub page, e.g. [How can I configure my C or C++ project?](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale#how-can-i-configure-my-c-or-c-project)

The problem at hand - as we found out using the `:ALEInfo` command - is, that clang-tidy is not correctly set up. It lacks a compilation database. There are two possible solutions to the problem:

- disable clang-tidy (and probably several more of the clang family of checkers)
- create a compilation database

You can use clang to create the compilation database as explained in [clang's docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html).
Using clang does *not* mean you have to build your binaries using clang. You can continue to build your binaries using GCC and use clang only for static code analysis. In my experience, this is a common setup.

If clang-tidy is installed on your system, clang is as well. So you should not  need to install additional packages. All you have to do is to configure your builds correctly. How it is done depends on your build system, which you don't mention in the question.

Should you be using CMake, the process is trivially easy by setting [`CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html). You may also have to create a symlink to `compile_commands.json` in your source root so ALE can find the file.

For other build systems, a lot of [questions and answers are available here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%20compilation%20database). If none of them answer your question, consider asking a new question. Be sure to include your specific setup in the question.

As to alternatives to clang, there are plenty available. GCC itself can be run in static analyzer mode (and ALE will do so) and there are proven tools like cppcheck and cpplint. Again, `:ALEInfo` will show a list of *Available Linters*. As I wrote above, the more you use the more you'll find.